# nodeca/js-yaml appending >- on long strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yaml

Using `js-yaml` npm package, i'm trying to manipulate a `.yaml` file.
while successfully able to manipulate, i'm getting a problem while saving a long string.

Actual:

```
  abvs_adas: >-
    c2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2RwaW9qbGtkZ2hqbGtzZGhmZ2psaGFzamhhandiZm0sYXNibmYsbWFuc2Y==`
```

Expected

```
  abvs_adas: c2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2Rhc2RwaW9qbGtkZ2hqbGtzZGhmZ2psaGFzamhhandiZm0sYXNibmYsbWFuc2Y==`
```

when setting `{lineWidth: 200}` it became as the expectes, but when i got a `base64` string containing 6000 chars, it appended that `>-` again (i've set increased `{lineWidth: 20000}`.

how can i not have this `>-` appended ?

I'm using `nodeyaml` package, doing: `nodeyaml.write('bla.yaml', doc, {lineWidth: 200},  function (err) { .. }` which internally does:

```
 await fs.writeFile(filename, yaml.dump(object, opts), {encoding, flag})
```

where

`opts` = `{lineWidth: 20000}`

`object` = `doc`

I've used `js-yaml`, but if you know an alternative which does:

1. load a `.yaml` which includes a very large strings
2. manipulate it
3. save it.

it's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{lineWidth: -1}` does the trick.

---

Explanation; inside the `js-yaml` package there is function named: `chooseScalarStyle` which sets the style, and the chosen style is: `STYLE_FOLDED` which later appending that `>-\n`.

while setting `{lineWidth: -1}` it make the style: `STYLE_PLAIN` which later just return the string as is.